# Delete file by non standard extension

Tags: python

I know how to delete files by extension but what if my files are looking like this:

```
update_24-08-2022_14-54.zip.001
```

Where last 3 digits can be between 001-029

Here is code that I'm using for standard zip files

```
files_in_directory = os.listdir(directory)
filtered_files = [file for file in files_in_directory if file.endswith(".zip")]
for file in filtered_files:
    path_to_file = os.path.join(directory, file)
    os.remove(path_to_file)
```

Comment: How about regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the double extensions are of the form `.zip.xyz`, with `xyz` being triple digits, you can use globbing:

```
import glob
import os

for path in glob.glob('*.zip.[0-9][0-9][0-9]'):
    os.remove(path)
```

(As a usual precaution, check first, by replacing `os.remove` with `print`).

If you have a specific directory, its name stored in `directory`, you can use:

```
import glob
import os

for path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*.zip.[0-9][0-9][0-9]')):
    os.remove(path)
```

There is no need to join the `directory` and `path` inside the for loop (as is the case in the question): `path` itself will already contain the `directory` name.